# Windows Vista Upgrade via Product Key

Tags: windows-vista, license-key

I just built a new computer and am without OS at the moment. I have a copy of Windows Vista Ultimate OEM (64-bit) on the way. I also have a copy of Windows Vista Home Premium OEM (64-bit) that I used on another computer.

My question is this: Can I install Home Premium on my system and use a trial for a few days and then, once I get my copy of Ultimate, use that product key and automatically upgrade Windows to Ultimate by using its key?

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am aware Vista Home cannot be upgrade to Ultimate. You can however install Windows Ultimate as a trail directly?

However according to [this](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/windows-vista/get/anytime-upgrade-overview.aspx) page you can do a direct upgrade, however I can recall that the only copies of the Vista media that had all editions where the Ultimate DVD's. This may have changed with SP1 and SP2.